# NoClassDefFoundError on MapActivity

Tags: android, google-maps

On some devices our App is crashing with NoClassDefFoundError when starting a Map Activity.

Yes, we have the permission and the library and all the needed things to run the MapActivity. It works fine 99.9% of all devices (all which have the google services...)

However, there are 2-3 devices i've never heard about (e.g. : Prestigio - PAP4040_DUO or MID - PAD-FMD700P or rockchip AN9G2)  which seems to not have the google services and no possibility to open the Map Activity.

is there any chance to detect this and maybe show something like "your phone does not support google maps, sorry"?

(Yes we could ignore thous 2-3 devices, but we try to support everything)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is there any chance to detect this and maybe show something like "your phone does not support google maps, sorry"?

If your `MapActivity` is not tied to a launcher icon, perhaps. My guess is that your `NoClassDefFoundError` is coming from `MapActivity` or something else from the Maps V1 SDK add-on. In that case, use `Class.forName()` to detect if you have a class from Maps V1 before trying to start any `MapActivity`.

[This sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Maps/NooYawkMapless) demonstrates this. The launcher icon is tied to a `Theme.NoDisplay` activity, which has the following `onCreate()`:

```
  public void onCreate(Bundle instanceState) {
    super.onCreate(instanceState);

    try {
      Class.forName("com.google.android.maps.MapActivity");
      startActivity(new Intent(this, NooYawk.class));
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
      Toast
            .makeText(this,
                       "Google Maps are not available -- sorry!",
                       Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
            .show();
    }

    finish();
  }
```

If our test to see if `MapActivity` exists succeeds, we can safely start a `MapActivity` (here named `NooYawk`). If we get an exception, we simply exit with a `Toast`.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. Seems legit for me, and i'll accept it soon, but: Do you know how to test this without having one of thous devices? We have a couple of BB10 devices here and we will test it on them (compile, sideload, test) but maybe for other people any hint?

Comment: @Christoph: Use an emulator image that does not have the Google APIs.

Comment: Tested in Emulator, works perfect. Thx if you could change 
catch (Exception e) {
to catch (ClassNotFoundException e), it would be fine as well (never catch everything)